# How do I get only the element values that match in the list in the Elastic Search?

Tags: list, sorting, elasticsearch, get, kibana

[Hi, there]

I want to create an ES query that only retrieves certain elements that match in the list.

**Here is my ES index schema.**

```
"test-es-2018":{
"aliases": {}, 
"mappings": { 
  "test-1": { 
    "properties": { 
      "categoryName": { 
        "type": "keyword", 
        "index": false 
      }, 
      "genDate": { 
        "type": "date" 
      }, 
      "docList": { 
        "properties": { 
          "rank": { 
            "type": "integer", 
            "index": false 
          }, 
          "doc-info": {
            "properties": { 
              "docId": { 
                "type": "keyword" 
              }, 
              "docName": { 
                "type": "keyword", 
                "index": false 
              }, 
            } 
          }
        } 
      }, 
      "categoryId": { 
        "type": "keyword" 
      }, 
    } 
  }
}
```

}

There are documents listed in the category. Documents in the list have their own information.

***search query in Kibana.**

```
source": { 
        "categoryName" : "food" , 
        "genDate" : 1577981646638, 
        "docList" [
        {
          "rank": 2, 
          "doc-info": {...} 
        },
        {
          "rank": 1, 
          "doc-info": {...} 
        },
        {
          "rank": 5, 
          "doc-info": {...}
        },
       ],
       "categoryId": "201"
       }
```

First, I want to get only the element value that match in the list.

I would like to see only documents with rank 1 in the list. However, if I query using `match` as below, the result is the same as ***search query in kibana**.

***match query in Kibana.**

```
GET test-es-2018/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "docList.rank": 1 } },
      ] 
    }
  }
}
```

In my opinion, it seems to print the entire list because it contains a document with rank one.

**What I want is:**

```
source": { 
        "categoryName" : "food" , 
        "genDate" : 1577981646638, 
        "docList" [
          {
            "rank": 1, 
            "doc-info": {...} 
          },
       ],
       "categoryId": "201"
       }
```

Is this possible?

Second, I want to sort the docList by rank. I tried sorting by creating a query like the following, but it was not sorted.

***sort query in Kibana.**

```
GET test-es-2018/_search? 
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {...}
  },
  "sort" : [
    {
      "docList.rank" : {
          "order" : "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**What I want is:**

```
source": { 
    "categoryName" : "food" , 
    "genDate" : 1577981646638, 
    "docList" [
    {
      "rank": 1, 
      "doc-info": {...} 
    },
    {
      "rank": 2, 
      "doc-info": {...} 
    },
    {
      "rank": 5, 
      "doc-info": {...}
    },
   ],
   "categoryId": "201"
   }
```

I do not know how to access the list. Is there a good idea for both of these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In general you could use [source filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) to retrieve only part of the document but this way it's not possible to exclude some fields based on their values.
2. As far as I know Elasticsearch doesn't support changing order of field values in the *_source*. Partly the desired result can be achieved by using `nested` fields along with `inner_hits -> sort` query expression. This way sorted subhits will be returned in the `inner_hits` section of the response.

P.S. Typically working with Elasticsearch you should consider indexed document as the smallest indivisible search unit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.